# Google Protobuf 'compiler is out of heap space'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, protocol-buffers

I generated the .h and .cc with the protoc.exe tool, when I included the pb.h in my solution it failed to compile

> test.pb.h(17): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space

I added the `/Zm` option (I attempted with all factors i.e `/Zm2000`, `/Zm200`, `/Zm1000` etc...

but the error still comes up ...

Any ideas please? as I am kinda stuck,

Thanks!

Proto file:

```
 package MSGTest;

 enum EnumMsg
 {
    EMF_A  = 1;
    EMF_B  = 2;
 }

 message MSGExtended
 {
     enum MSG_TYPE
     {
        MSGT_SP = 1;
     }

    required  MSG_TYPE type = 1;
 }

 message MSGExtended2
 {
     enum MSG_TYPE
     {
        MSGT_SP = 1;
     }

    required  MSG_TYPE type = 1;
 }

 message MSGExtendedb
 {
    required EnumMsg        from = 1; 
    optional MSGExtended    msga = 2;
    optional MSGExtendedb   msgb = 3;
 }
```

Comment: Take a look inside the generated files.  Is there infinite recursive inclusion or something?  Is this happening for all protobuf files, or just a particularly complex one?

Comment: Also your title says Visual Studio 2012 (or did), but you used the `visual-studio-2013` tag.  Are you seeing this problem with both versions?

Comment: My apologies, I am only testing this with Visual Studio 2012, the protobuf is pretty simple posting it in question

Comment: `MSGExtendedb` contains itself?  Was that intended to be a `MSGExtended2` instead?

Comment: And it would still be helpful to know whether this problem occurs with any other protocols, or only this particular one.

Answer (score 1):

Line 17 in auto-generated *.pb.h files is always the same, it is

```
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
```

or, together with neighboring block:

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2004000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 2004000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

Whenever any of above two conditions is true, instead of printing error message, VS2012 (in my case) gives up with misleading "fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space".
The reason for a condition to be true was a slight mess in my system: c:/opt/bin contained an older protoc.exe (version 2.4.0), whereas includes with GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION and GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION definitions were of version 2.5.1 (2005001), making the second condition to be true.
Copying proper protoc.exe to c:/opt/bin fixed the problem.